# counting records on per hour, per day and create multindex DataFrame as output

Tags: python, pandas

Sample DataFrame :

`process_id | app_path | start_time`

the desired output data frame should be multi-Indexed based on the date and time value in start_time column with unique dates as first level of index and one hour range as second level of index the count of records in each time slot should be calculated

```
def activity(self):
    # find unique dates from db file
    columns = self.df['start_time'].map(lambda x: x.date()).unique()

    result = pandas.DataFrame(np.zeros((1,len(columns))), columns = columns)
    for i in range(len(self.df)):
        col = self.df.iloc[i]['start_time'].date()
        result[col][0] = result.get_value(0, col) + 1

    return result
```

I have tried the above code which gives the output as :

`15-07-2014  16-7-2014  17-07-2014   18-07-2014
    3217        2114       1027         3016`
I want to count records on per hour basis as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be helpful to start your question with some sample data. Since you didn't, I assumed the following is representative of your data (looks like `app_path` was not being used):

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=10000, freq='1Min')
df = pd.DataFrame(randint(size=len(rng), low=100, high = 500), index=rng)
df.columns = ['process_id']
```

It looks like you could benefit from exploring the `groupby` method in Pandas data frames. Using groupby, your example above become a simple one-liner:

```
df.groupby( [df.index.year, df.index.month, df.index.day] ).count()
```

and grouping by hour means simply adding hour to the group:

```
df.groupby( [df.index.year, df.index.month, df.index.day, df.index.hour] ).count()
```

Don't recreate the wheel in Pandas, use the methods provided for much more readable, as well as faster, code.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I'll have to make start_time as my index for dataframe. This gives me count for each column but I want only a single column representing the count

Comment: No, you don't have to use the index. But that is a typical use case for time series data. If the start_time is in a different column then use that column name instead of index.